# Requests through Nginx-uwsgi-Django are so slow

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi

I thought using Nginx-uwsgi-Django triad will be much better and faster than Apache/mod_wsgi combination, but it seems like there is something not right. When I make a regular web request to Nginx, and monitor uwsgi logs I see this:

`[pid: 15529|app: 0|req: 1/1] 172.28.128.1 () {40 vars in 624 bytes} [Wed Aug 27 12:06:23 2014] GET / => generated 1757 bytes in 2262 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 2 headers in 73 bytes (1 switches on core 0)`

NOTICE here the 2262 msecs latency

And here is my uwsgi configuration:

```
[uwsgi]
chdir           = /vagrant/one/main_project

# Django's wsgi file (path starting from chdir/)
#wsgi-file       = /vagrant/one/main_project/main_project/wsgi.py

enable-threads = true

#pythonpath      = /vagrant/one/bin/python2.7

# the virtualenv (full path)
home              = /vagrant/one/


# process-related settings
# master
master          = true
# maximum number of worker processes
processes       = 10
# the socket (use the full path to be safe)
socket           = /tmp/uwsgi.sock

# ... with appropriate permissions - may be needed      -
chmod-socket    = 666
# clear environment on exit
vacuum          = true
```

After all, I run it like this:

`uwsgi --ini uwsgi_config_one.ini -w  main_project.wsgi`

it works fine but with 2262 msecs latency ... Why would that happen?

Comment: can you show timing for Apache combination ? May be your code really so slow ?

Comment: There's no reason to think that nginx/uwsgi would be faster than apache/mod_wsgi: any difference in performance would be completely irrelevant next to the speed of your code itself.

Comment: that time is counted from the moment the connection is accepted() by uWSGI, so it is effectively the time spent by your app/code. You should profile it to know what is happening.

Comment: Thanks all for your comments ... no code is involved in this evaluation, it's django's "It works" page .. so the question stands: is that time normal

Comment: @roberto. I there any reason why this stack should be slow, keeping in mind that it is just the welcome page of Django that is behind uwsgi, even 500 msecs is so much considering that this stack is locally hosted .. What do you think?

Comment: i'm having a similar issue with Flask. Most requests are fast but every now and then I'll get one that takes a really long time. I've been unable to figure out why.